# Relational Table SQL Query Optimization/Performance Issue?

Tags: sql

I have query optimization issue as follows.

I have two related tables.

```
Commodity (This table has 75 Thousand records)
  CommodityID (PK)
  CommodityName

CommoditySupplier  (This table has approx 800 Million records)
  CommoditySupplierID (PK)
  SupplierID (FK)
  CommodityID (FK)
```

I am executing following query to list SupplierIDs having CommodityName 'SearchString'

```
SELECT SuppllierID
FROM CommoditySupplier 
WHERE CommodityID IN (SELECT CommodityID FROM Commodity WHERE CommodityName Like '%SearchString%')
```

Problem is, it is extremely slow. It takes more than 30-40 minutes to execute. Sometimes even more than that.
please guide me to optimize the query. Or Should I change the structure in someway?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products have (somewhat) different optimizing tricks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `JOIN` or `EXISTS` is faster:

```
SELECT cs.SuppllierID
FROM CommoditySupplier cs
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Commodity c
              WHERE c.CommodityID = cs.CommodityId AND
                    c.CommodityName Like '%SearchString%'
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `Commodity(CommodityID, CommodityName)`.

Because of the search using wildcards, this may still not have very good performance.  If you can use `=` or `IN`, use one of those constructs instead of `LIKE`.  Otherwise, you may need to consider a full text index.